# TimeSpan.TotalMinutes without seconds

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am using the code

```
var minutesPassed = (DateTime.UtcNow - conversionsList.Last().DateStamp).TotalMinutes;
```

to calculate how much minutes passed between two dates. The result which I get looks like

> 254.54445556

I get minutes and seconds. How to get result which would contain only minutes like this

> 254

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just explicitly convert the result to `int`:

```
var minutesPassed = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - conversionsList.Last().DateStamp).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Converting `254.54445556` to an `int` wouldn't round up?

Comment: @Curt no :) it will give you 254.

Comment: @Curt I think Eren is right. The float will be converted to int. This is that I need.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Math.Floor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx) to convert 254.xxxx to 254:

```
var minutesPassed = Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow - conversionsList.Last().DateStamp).TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just get the int part

```
int minutes = (int) (DateTime.UtcNow - conversionsList.Last().DateStamp).TotalMinutes;
```

this will get you the int part of the value.

EDIT: as far as rounding of value is considered. That is not true. Consider the following:

```
 double d = 254.99999999999d;
 int test = (int)d;
```

Here `test` will hold `254`, not `255`

The only problem with the explicit cast is [OverFlowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx)

Comment: @Curt, it won't, I tried this in Visual studio and it is giving 254. double d = 254.54445556d;
            int test = (int)d; Correct me if my test is wrong

Comment: Cheers I always thought it rounded to the nearest int. Surprised!